# Qt creator 4.15.0 issue with decimal points in method hasAcceptableInput()

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, decimal-point

I have a project **Qt Creator 4.5.1 / Qt 5.10.1 /  C++**  . Everything worked fine. Then I migrated to **Qt Creator 4.15.0 / Qt 5.15.2  /  C++**  . I have both versions installed on the same Computer/Win10. I copied the project and used it on my new Qt. On my new Qt-Version I get errors processing double values of a lineEdit:

I have a checking-routine for my lineEdit entries that checks if the Input is acceptable. For that I use the **hasAcceptableInput()** - method. In my previous Qt version everything is OK; In my new version double values seperated with a *point* as decimal point ( e.g. 3.15) produce a return value "false". On the other hand double values seperated with a *comma* as decimal point ( e.g.3,15) would be OK ( return value "true"). In my old Qt-Version both cases return "true"

**Does anybody know the reason for that ?**

**Is there maybe a setting in Qt creator where I have to set the decimal points?**

Comment: It sounds like it could be related to your locale. Are you using a decimal point or comma (or something else) in your language?

Comment: I have both versions of Qt running on the same system. One works the other one doesn`t

Comment: Yes, but different versions of Qt. Perhaps the newer version is picking up whatever locale settings you have in a different way than the old version did.

Comment: Any more info? If you solved it - please share an answer!